Why is my PHP server code returning HTML code as response when request is sent to it, in live server?
This is my code:
domain/url/login/index.php:
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['empno'])) {
        header("Location: ../homepage/index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        function preventBack() {
            window.history.forward();
        }
    
        setTimeout(preventBack(), 0);
        window.onunload = function() {
            null
        };
    </script>
    <title>My website</title>
    <style>....</style>
</head>
<body>

    <!--some HTML code here-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "../backend.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        let data = "input=get_data";
        xhr.send(data);
     </script>
</body>
</html>

domain/url/backend.php:
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    require "db_particulars.php";

    $con=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$pass);
    $connection=mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

    if(!$connection){
        echo "Connection to database failed! Please try again";
    }
    else{
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
            if ($_POST["input"] == "get_data"){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee_master` GROUP BY `Department` ORDER BY `Department`";
                $result = $con->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    $final = array();
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        array_push($final,$row["Department"]);
                    }
                    echo json_encode($final);
                }
                else
                    echo "No data found";
            }
        }
    }
?>

While this code works perfectly in my localhost XAMPP server, when I run it in my live server, it just returns the parent script (login/index.php's) HTML code. I am unable to find the reason behind this. Someone please guide me on this.
I even tried commenting the connection to the database code and wrote a simple code:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Output debug information
echo "Debug Information:\n";
echo "Request Method: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . "\n";
echo "POST Data: " . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n";

// Set appropriate headers
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
?>

But it still returns the index.php's HTML code.
My project hierarchy inside my subdomain folder is:
login
  |__ index.php

backend.php


Okay, I think I see it. Where you utilize ../ for files this may not be true on a live domain. This could potentially exploit root files. Can you not just write it out as          xhr.open("POST", "backend.php", true);

You mean VScode's Live Server?

But backend.php is inside the root directory, whereas index.php is inside the login folder inside the root directory. Edit: I tried it, still returns the same

@brombeer no, in my purchased server

Doesn't matter, you're making an XHR requert for ../backend.php that's completely incorrect. If the server processed the request it would literally instead of login/index.php it'd be trying login/backend.php; whether that's right still it's not correct.

Do change your XHR requests so that root is represented as "/" so if you have a link www.example.com/test/test/hoorah/backend.php you'd always make a request to it no matter where on your site you are by making it out to "/test/test/hoorah/backend.php". This is best practice and safe for web development.

I tried xhr.open("POST", "backend.php", true);, but it still returns the html code

@BGPHiJACK using ../ in client-side relative URLs, is perfectly valid. "This could potentially exploit root files." - no, the web server itself will prevent HTTP access above the document root.

What happens when you go to http://domain/url/backend.php directly in your browser? Do you get an "empty" result then (as to be expected, based on that script's content, when the method was not POST) - or do you still get the HTML content of the login script returned?

Yes I still get the HTML content of the login script returned. In fact, the login/index.php opens up

Are you using any .htaccess files with any redirects/rewrites?

Your last code snippet (that "simple code") is invalid. You can't add headers after you've already outputted data (those echo's). All headers must be sent before any output what so ever.

Check your browser's Network tool when you're loading the page, and watch what happens to the XHR request to backend.php. Like M. Eriksson I suspect something somewhere may be doing a redirect (which you'll hopefully be able to see in the Network tool) - if it's not your PHP code which is doing it, then maybe a .htaccess file on the server has such rules configured.
